# How to get a value from an Array via a class in Winforms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I have a class called `Game.cs` and in the class I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Simon
{
    class Game
    {
        public int[] TheArray = new int[1000];

        private bool m_Play;
        public bool Play
        {
            set { m_Play = value; }
            get { return m_Play; }
        }

        public Game()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                TheArray[i] = rnd.Next(0, 4); // between 0 and 3
            }

        }


    }
}
```

I want to be able to call `TheArray` from my form. I want the loop to iterate based on the times I click `button5` and then I want to click my buttons programmatically based on what my array returns. On my form I have 4 buttons called, `button1`,`button2`,`button3` and `button4`.

Once I click on `button5` my code needs to click the button based on the array each time it loops through `TheArray`

So far I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Simon
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Game m_game;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("box1");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("box2");
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("box3");
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("box4");
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Determine which button to click based on TheArray
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "latest int"?

Comment: I want the loop to iterate based on the times i click `button5` and then i want to click my buttons programmatically based on what my array returns..

Comment: Unless you make Game static, you need an object to get TheArray.

Comment: How are you going to determine when `button5` can stop collecting clicks?

Comment: When the loop ends.. or when i stop clicking. To be honest button 5 is just so i can test the loop and the randomness.

Comment: side comment: your `for` loop can be rewritten in proper C#: `TheArray = Enumerable.Range(0,8).Select(x => random.Next(0,4).ToArray();` - and I strongly suggest using a `List<int>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

To click on the buttons based on the array (I'm assuming `0` in the array corresponds to `button1`, etc, you could try something like this:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button[] button = { button1, button2, button3, button4 };
     for (int i = 0; i < m_game.TheArray.Length; i++)
     {
         button[m_game.TheArray[i]].PerformClick();
     }
}
```

As a side note, as @ThunderGr pointed out in a comment, you'd have to create an instance of your game or else make it static.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton, did either of these answers help?

Answer (score 1):

In the form declaration define `Game MyGameClass=new Game();`.

You code has lots of gaps, though. In order to get the last int, you need to also define a `public int CurrentInt=0;` in the Game Class and do a `CurrentInt++;` from within `Game()`.

Now, you can do a `int theInt=MyGameClass.TheArray[MyGameClass.CurrentInt];` from within the button5 event and implement a switch statement to find which button to click.

Of course, this is still inefficient.
Perhaps it would be better if you declared a `public int GetLastInt()` in Game that would `return TheArray[CurrentInt];`.